# databricks secret scope 'bad request'

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

getting a 'bad request' error  after following the below process in command prompt, please correct me..

```
pip install databricks-cli
databricks configure –-token

Databricks Host (should begin with https://): <your databricks URL>
Token: <your token>

databricks secrets create-scope --scope <scope name>
```

result:
**Error: b'Bad Request'**

Comment: Probably either your URL or token is wrong.

Comment: add `--debug` flag - it will say more

Comment: @Matt URL and token are correct

Comment: @AlexOtt Error is as below - 
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
Bad Request for url: https://eastus2.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create

Answer (score 1):

In your command we need to add initial manage principle as users to resolve the issue.

Note: While pasting the token, paste it carefully, if possible as below process:
[image]

Below is the command:

> databricks secrets create-scope --scope newscope08
> --initial-manage-principal "users"

Below is the execution in cmd:

[image]

Also have a look on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes) on scopes to understand about prerequisites and passing the parameters.

Need to make sure that we have Databricks Permium Plan.